# Repeatedly execute functions in app at regular intervals

Tags: android

I have created an android app that is now required to upload latitude and longitude every 6 minutes. This needs to start after log in and end upon closing the app or logging out, and remain running when the phone goes into idle mode or other apps are visited.

Google suggests the following options;

1. Create a service and put a timer task in it.
2. Use an alarm manager.

Which of these two options are better? Are there any other options?

Comment: Thanks Mark for correcting grammer mistake in question.

Comment: I think service + timer would be preferrable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you will definitely need a `Service`. `Activity`s cannot be relied on, as once paused, (e.g. another app is visited) there is absolutely no guarantee they will not be aborted without even `onDestroy()` being called.

`AlarmManager` is the most reliable way of triggering the 6-minute polling you need, as this will be executed even if the phone is sleeping for a long time. Use this to trigger your service (which may have been stopped during the 6-minute lull). This is the only option I know of that will be the most reliable.

`TimerTask` will not work if the `Service`, `Activity` or process is ended.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create master activity in which call locationmanager on uithread,that gives you lat-long at your position changed and at time of logout just remove all updates of location manager

Comment: hi akash, want to upload lat long at each 6 minutes thorough out app.

Comment: each 6 minutes. should start handler repeatedly in anctivity context?. and what if activity destroyed.

Comment: then use timer with schedule

Comment: Done the same. but not preferable. some timers when phone in idle for long time, then timer task stops working.